# There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [tomcat7x]

Tags: tomcat, maven, maven-plugin, maven-cargo

I have the following in my pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <wait>true</wait>
        <container>
            <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
            <type>remote</type>
        </container>
        <configuration>
            <type>remote</type> 
            <properties>
                <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>http://<myhost>:8080/manager</cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
                <cargo.remote.username>admin</cargo.remote.username>
                <cargo.remote.password>password</cargo.remote.password>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
        <deployer>
            <type>installed</type>
            <deployables>
                <deployable>
                    <groupId>com.mycode</groupId>
                    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
                    <type>war</type>
                </deployable>
            </deployables>
        </deployer>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-container</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deployer-deploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-container</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deployer-undeploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>verify-deploy</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deployer-deploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution> 
        <execution>
            <id>clean-undeploy</id>
            <phase>pre-clean</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deployer-undeploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution> 
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After this I issue command `mvn deploy` however I get the error below:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.3.1:deployer-deploy
>   (start-container) on project fismacm: Execution start-container of
>   goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.3.1:deployer-deploy
>   failed: Cannot create configuration. There's no registered
>   configuration for the parameters (container [id = [tomcat6x], type =
>   [remote]], configuration type [remote]). Valid types for this
>   configuration are:

I can successfully access `http://<myhost>:8080/manager` from my browser. Version of tomcat I'm running is 7.

Comment: The `<deployables>` tag inside `<deployer>` does not seem right. The `<deployables>` is a top level configuration element according to the [Reference Guide](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide).

Comment: Also, the `<type>remote</type>` is not an allowed type in that section. It should be `standalone`, `existing` or `runtime`. This is also according to the Reference Guide.

Comment: note that you have "id=tomcat7x" in the subject but "id=tomcat6x" in the error message... however, I agree with @maba that the real problem is your "type" parameter, just like the error message says.

Answer (score 1):

@maba : there are two kinds of type tags

```
<container>
    <type></type>
</container>
```

there you can have embedded / remote

And then

```
<configuration>
    <type>runtime</type>
</configuration>
```

Where in fact you can have the values you mentionned : standalone, existing or runtime

@birdy : I am facing the same issue : if you got rid of it please mention it :) Adnd by the way, the log error also gives you the possible types you can have, but you didn't paste it in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this question while investigating a slightly different issue.  Hopefully this can help someone in the future:

I believe

```
<configuration>
    <type>remote</type>
</configuration>
```

should be:

```
<configuration>
    <type>runtime</type>
</configuration>
```

The following is an excerpt from a pom.xml that works for me:

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <container>
                <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                <type>remote</type>
            </container>
            <configuration>
                <type>runtime</type>
                <properties>
                    <cargo.hostname>hostname</cargo.hostname>
                    <cargo.servlet.port>port</cargo.servlet.port>
                    <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>http://${cargo.hostname}:${cargo.servlet.port}/manager</cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
                    <cargo.remote.username>username</cargo.remote.username>
                    <cargo.remote.password>password</cargo.remote.password>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <deployables>
                <deployable>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                </deployable>
            </deployables>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```